# Recursive Relation Help for dynamic programming 2d Plane algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

So I've been working on an algorithm. The task I'm trying to accomplish is: consider a 2D plane there are targets that are randomly distributed between a y upper bound and lower bound. This set is T. T1 is marked with coordinates(X,Y). There is a set S of sensors that are guaranteed to cover every target each sensor has a radius 1 and an (X,Y) coordinate. Each target has a cost (c) that is a weight. So my task is to find a minimum weight or cost for a set S' that covers each sensor.

So I know that there is a recursive relation between the disks that "dominate" or "control" other disks but I'm having trouble seeing a property that shows how to utilize the dominance of the disks. I got this far:

Let D+ be the set of disks whose centre lies above the strip (upper disks).

Let D- be the set of disks whose centre lies below the strip (lower disks).

Consider an upper disk d, and d intersects a vertical line L. Another upper disk d' is said to be controlled or dominated by d, if one of the following holds:
(1)d' does not intersect L
(2)the lower intersection endpoint of d' and L is higher than the lower intersection endpoint of d and L
(3)the lower intersection endpoint of d' and L is identical to the lower intersection endpoint of d and L, but the centre of d' is on the right of the centre of d.

Similarly, for a lower disk d, and d intersects a vertical line L. Another lower disk d' is said to be controlled or dominated by d, if one of the following holds:
(1)d' does not intersect L
(2)the upper intersection endpoint of d' and L is lower than the upper intersection endpoint of d and L
(3)the upper intersection endpoint of d' and L is identical to the upper intersection endpoint of d and L, but the centre of d' is on the right of the centre of d.
Example:[image: three sensors with radius 1]

But I’m having trouble finalizing the algorithm. any help? Is that clear?

Thanks,
Christopher

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your question.  I think you might find a more helpful answer from the theoretical CS Stack Exchange crowd http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or even the new CS beta http://cs.stackexchange.com/  Good luck with your problem.

Comment: @Chris: Can you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518402/minimum-cost-subset-of-sensors-covering-targets it seems like a stripped down version of this problem. May be the answers would be of some help. Cheers!

Comment: It's pretty much the same problem. It seems derived. But nobody seems to be able to think of a more dynamic way to solve it.

Comment: So what I've tried is to create sets for each sensor listing targets S1{t1,t2} S2{t2,t3} etc. but I can not find a way to do this and select the minimum cost in polynomial time recursively

Comment: This is looking like it might be related to the Steiner tree problem, which is NP-hard.  I'm not sure, though.