# Minimum cost subset of sensors covering targets

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a question in dynamic programming, If I have a set of sensors covering targets ( a target might be covered by mutiple sensors) how can I find the minimum cost subset of sensors knowing that each sensors has its own cost?
I thought a lot about this, but I cant reach the recursive forumla to write my program? greedy algorithm gives me wrong minimum cost subset sometimes, and my problem is that sensors overlap in covering targets, any help?

For Example:
I have set of sensors with cost/weight = {s1:1,s2:2.5,s3:2} and I have three targets = {t1,t2,t3}. sensors coverage as following:={s1:t1 t2,s2:t1 t2 t3,s3:t2 t3} I need to get minimum cost subset by dynamic programming, for the above example if I use greedy algorithm I would get s1,s3 but the right answer is s2 only

Comment: minimum cost of what? cover all targets with the minmum number of sensors?

Comment: This is an NP-hard problem (see [e.g. here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem))

Comment: Is this the same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500227/recursive-relation-help-for-dinamic-programming-2d-plane-algorithm ? Where did you find this problem? can we see the original version of it? (rather than your description of it)

Comment: I am trying to write a program that restrict that it should be in dynamic programming, thats why I am not reaching a solution

Comment: I dont have any disks? and its not a graph, actually my sister asked me that question, her university professor told them the question(thats what she told me, like the above) but I have been trying for that for 3 days with no luck

Comment: `weight(s1 + s3) = 2`, but `weight(s2) = 2.5`, so how come the right answer is `s2`?

Comment: sorry I just updated it ... s1+s3=3

Comment: Got some branch-and-bound, not dynamic programming, algorithm, if you're interested... got no formal correctness proff, though.

Comment: actually it should be dynamic,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check section 3 it labels the 
Dynamic programming algorithm for the MWCDC

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:5vPrmVg7jDMJ:www.cs.iit.edu/~wan/Journal/tcs10.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESglfvp6XtFIkqDZZ-E-Tun4AWPTZV_V7z32pTvJ05K6tdkCoefpsAxPxdK44jYDvPNLDEwYI8uK-PMlLGthsaV8-ow63utalgWPnyLrUUBKhoTTVuYwUiKSHlCXU-HXKHVeHvh4&sig=AHIEtbQGka8F39MaT8yAy4G9Kvv8TPsvJA

Comment: page 5 lemma 1 is what your talking about i think

Answer (score 0):

I thought of something but I'm not 100% confident about it, here it goes:

```
S = {s1 : 1, s2 : 2.5, s3 : 2}
M = {s1 : t1t2, s2 : t1t2t3, s3 : t2t3}
```

Now, we build a matrix representing the `target x sensor` map:

```
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
```

So the rows are targets `(t1 -> R0, t2 -> R1 etc.)`, and columns represent which sensors cover them.

Next we process row-by-row while collecting the list of sensors that will cover the current target set. For an example:

```
Row - 0:
{t1} -> [s1 : 1], [s2 : 2.5]
```

Notice that we're building a list of answers. Then we proceed to the next row, where we need to add `t2` to our set of targets while calculating the minimum sensor weight required to do so.

```
Row - 1:
{t1, t2} -> [s1 : 1], [s2 : 2.5]
```

Note that nothing changed on the RHS because both `s1` and `s2` covers `t2` as well. Next the final row:

```
Row - 2:
{t1, t2, t3} -> [s1, s3 : 3], [s2 : 2.5]
```

Notice that I had to add `s3` to the first answer because it had the minimum weight covering `t3`.

A final walk through the list of answers would reveal that `[s2 : 2.5]` is the best candidate.

Now, I'm not that confident with dynamic programming, so not sure whether what I'm doing here is correct. Will be great if someone can confirm / dispute what I have done here.

**EDIT:** May be it makes sense to have the columns sorted according to the weight of the sensors. So that it becomes easy to select the sensor with the lowest weight covering a given target.

Comment: I cant understand how did u move from row 1 to row 2 ... I mean why did u add s3 to s1 instead of s2?

Comment: Because `s1` doesn't cover `t3`, so we must add a sensor that covers it (with a minimum cost). On the other hand `s2` covers `t3`. This information can be read from the matrix (2D array) quite fast (it's a bool). Please note that I'm not 100% sure about this answer.

Comment: I thought of ur answer and it makes sense but it doesnt get me to a recursive formula for dynamic programming
whats OPT(i) = Min(OPT(i-1)+|Si|,OPT(P(j))) ... what is P(j)?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. As I said, not an expert in dynamic programming. Let's wait for someone else to answer. Cheers!

Comment: btw s3 covers t2 why u didnt include that in ur answer?(in step 2, Row-1: ) ?

Comment: s3 covers t2 but its not considered in ur solution in that step

Comment: Why do you want to add `s3`? `s1` and `s2` already cover `t2`, which is the current target being added to our set.

Comment: what is exactly ur algorithm in adding sensors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19956/discussion-between-asiri-rathnayake-and-farajnew)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposal, it's not a dynamic programming, but is the best I can come up with, the problem is interesting and worth a discussion.

---

Define "partial solution" to be tuple `(T,S,P,C)` where `T` is covered
targets, `S` is included sensors, `P` is the set of pending targets, `C` is
the cost.

`W` is the current working set of partial solutions, which
initially contains only `({}, {}, X, 0)`, i.e. cost zero, nonempty is only the set of pending targets. `W` can be maintained as a heap.

```
W = { ({}, {}, X, 0) }
repeat
  p = select and remove from W the partial solution with the minimum cost
  if p.P is empty
     return p
  t = select from p.P the target, covered by the minimum number of sensors
  for each sensor s, covering t, which is not in p'.S
     p' = new partial solution, copy of p;
     p'.S += {s};
     p'.C += cost(s);
     for each target t' covered by s
       p'.T += {t};
       p'.P -= {t};
     end for
     W += {p'}
  end for
end repeat
```

Comment: since W is empty at the first line in the loop which is to select and remove from W .... u would get an empty p and return empty!

Comment: No, W is initialized just before the "repeat".

Comment: Thank you what you wrote works but still its not dynamic programming

Comment: I thought of something like this 
two dimensional array that contains all posible sensor combination, each row has a maximuim number of sensors as row number +1 and has all combinations for example for row two we have two sensors in each cell but in each column the combination of sensors in those for example row 2 : s1s2,s1s3,s2s3 then I find the minimum cost recursivly but I couldnt reach the recursive formula... any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my algorithm for this problem. Its a recursive approach for the problem.

Pseudocode :

```
MinimizeCost(int cost , List targetsReached, List sensorsUsed, int current_sensor) {

if(targetsReached.count == no_of_targets ) {
    if(cost < mincost ) {
          mincost = cost;
          minList = sensorsUsed;
            }       
    return;
    }

   if(current_sensor > maxsensors)
         return;
   else {
         // Current Sensor is to be ignored 
     MinimizeCost(cost , targetsReached, sensorsUsed, current_sensor +1 );

         // Current Sensor is Considered 
     int newcost = cost + sensor_cost[current_sensor];  
     sensorsUsed.Add(current_sensor);
     AddIfNotExists(targetsReached, targets[current_sensor]);
     MinimizeCost(newcost, targetsReached, sensorsUsed, current_sensor+1);
  }
}
```

The Sensors_Used List can be avoided if those details are not needed.

Further Memoization can be introduced to this if the TargetsReached List can be mapped to an int. Then [Current_Sensor, TargetsReached] value can be saved and used when needed to avoid repetition. Hope this helps. There might be better approaches though.